Django partial template rendering not updating the page, but showing up in console
I have a django-based webpage I am working on (Django version 5.0).  This page allows for clicking on a item in a table and the intention is to display subitems related to the item, without redrawing the whole page.  Though my subtemplate is being seen by Django and acted upon, instead of updating the portion of the html in the page, the resulting html is being dumped in the console.  Here are some code snippets:
main.html contains, among many other things, the following positioned where I want the content:
{% include '_subtemplate.html' %}

_subtemplate contains:
{% for subitem in subitems %}
<tr>
  <td><a onclick='mySubItemClick("{{ subitem.date }}")'>{{ subitem.date }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ subitem.my_note }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

views.py contains:
def get_my_subitems(requests, site_id):
    subitems = # code to get a list of objects
    return render(request, '_subtemplate.html', { 'subitems': subitems })

urls.py contains a correct path entry in urlpatterns:
path('myitems/mysubitems/<int:site_id>/', views.get_my_subitems, name='get_my_subitems'),

I have a javascript file that contains a method which makes a working ajax call where 'path: /myitems/mysubitems/' + obj.site_id
Instead of seeing my list of subitem content reload in the html page, when I open the browser console, I am seeing the correctly templated html there and not in the page.
<tr>
  <td><a onclick='mySubItemClick("June 13, 2024")'>June 13, 2024</a></td>
  <td>misc notes...</td>
</tr>

There are no errors in the javascript console or the django server.  Clearly, I am getting my data and formatting it properly, but include seems like it is dropping the ball at the end.

Well, I did not want to do this, nor do I understand why I cannot use the above, but simply using the response, from the ajax call and doing an append works:
$('#subitems tbody').append(resp);

I don't like this answer since it seems to avoid the very power of django templating and spreads this handling into javascript.
